# Object Properties in Browser's Console

Tags: javascript, json, browser-console

Whenever i log any **javascript object** into **browser**, I am keen to explore it by expanding what is inside in the **console window**,
As one such example is

```
console.log(console);
```

I sure found what is inside, But the real query starts now,
When i expand the object it has a property called **__proto__** with its sub-properties inside, then again this has a property of **contructor** and the cycle goes on as it has **__proto__** and again and so on.

**Does it end ?**

If **Yes**, what does this multiple repetition denotes ?

If **No**, Why doesn't browser hangs on printing such infinite object ?

- Any Leads highly appreciated

Thanks & Regards
Shohil Sethia

Comment: You might want to read more on what [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and inheritance are. Tldr the chain doesn't go on forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If Yes, what does this multiple repetition denotes ?

Derek has already given you a link explaining prototype chain.

> If No, Why doesn't browser hangs on printing such infinite object ?

`__proto__` is a special property and will be handled in special way. Instead lets take a generic example:

```js
var a = {
  nest : function() {
    this.b = this; 
  }
}

a.nest();
```

This will create an object `a` that has a property `b` that points to the main object `a` itself.

If you do `console.log(a)` you will see the similar behavior as you saw in case of `__proto__`. You can go on expanding property `b` N number of times and it will always show an object that has a property `b` and a method `nest`.

In this case browser doesn't hang because it iterates on only one level of properties. When you try to expand property `b` it will again iterate on only 1 level of sub-properties. It never iterates on nested properties and hence doesn't face any issue. On the other hand if you try to use `JSON.stringify(a)` it will give an error about circular reference because to generate string from the object it has to iterate on all nested properties.

Comment: So on every click on the Object it iterates on next one Sub-Level of properties, Is that what you meant ?
Alright something new i have never come through.
Thanks !